# How to check if all values in a boolean pandas series is of one type and apply logic based on the if condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

I have pandas series like so:

series:

```
True
False
False
```

How do I check the series to see if all values are True or False, and apply an if condition if they are all of one type?

Something like this:

```
if all series.values ==False:
   do something
```

Edit:

changed series to test @Wen-Ben example

```
False
False
False
```

Comment: So does this question imply other types (such as NaN and strings) can also occur in a Series?

Comment: Is there a difference if they are all True or all False? Or do you just care about it being unique either way?

Comment: @coldspeed no these will always be boolean values, no NaNs

Comment: @ALollz I want to only know if they are all True or False, If one of the values is True and others False, I want my IF/ELSE conditions to do some other things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `all`

```
(~s).all()
Out[5]: False
```

As Cold mentioned

```
s.is_unique&(s.iloc[0]==False)
```

Comment: @coldspeed Yes you are right ,when there is NaN or other string  will cause the problem

Comment: what is the iloc for and why is it only comparing the False?

Comment: @RustyShackleford first your series should be unique  then if the first one is False , then all should be False(Both of them true will return True )